# How do i make my charachter ontop of the background? As it shows underneath

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in python for a school project, and I'm trying to make a simple shooter when you just go up and down shooting enemies. However I am having trouble bringing the player above the background.

### Code

```py
import pygame, sys

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((100,100))
        self.image.fill((255,255,255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (screen_width/2,screen_height/2))

    def update(self):
        self.rect.center = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


# general setup
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# game screen
screen_width = 1920
screen_height = 1080
screen = pygame .display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
background = pygame.image.load("BackGround.png")

# player
player = Player()
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group.add(player)
player = pygame.image.load("spriteshd00.png")

# caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Wild-West Shooter")

# makes game quit
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    #drawing
    pygame.display.flip()
    player_group.draw(screen)
    player_group.update()
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    theApp = App()
    theApp.on_execute()
```

Comment: have looked for pygame tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the character after the background:

```py
while True:
    # handel events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame:quit()
            sys.exit()

    # update the game states and positions of objects
    player_group.update()

    # draw the background
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    # draw objects
    player_group.draw(screen)

    # update display
    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

---

Additionally you have to pass the player image to the `Player` class:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (screen_width//2, screen_height//2))
```

```py
# player
player_image = pygame.image.load("spriteshd00.png")
player = Player(player_image)
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group.add(player)
```

Comment: Thank you. this works, quick question though it does not show the image of the character it just shows a white box. I tried putting player = pygame.imgame.load("the name") underneath the draw objects but that didnt work

Comment: @Karma I've extended the answer.

Comment: thank you very much, i can finish this project now